# Commit PDF file to GitHub in Eclipse

Tags: github

I can't seem to add a PDF file to my GitHub repository. Are there settings somewhere to allow this? I've tried committing the files (they don't show up on the list of files), adding the files, and doing an 'add files to index' on my project.

Comment: Is there a .gitignore file in your repository?

Comment: @reto there was; I removed the *.pdf and that did it. Thanks--did not know about that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't seem to add a file, you can check if a gitignore rule is the cause:

```
git check-ignore -v
```

You will see if a `.gitignore` rule is responsible.

If you want to keep that rule *except* for that file, you can *force* the add:

```
git add -f your.pdf
```

That will add the pdf file, even though it wasn't visible in the `git status`.